# How to set filter for ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to set the filter for the second ng-repeat to handle with the first one by displaying only the result of the current month. `bookings` and  `booking.monthDate` is similar to `month`

Thanks you for helping to get the best practice here with Angular.js

```
       .dataContainer{"ng-repeat"=>"month in months"}
          %h2
            %span.monthResa {{month}}

          .monthDetailContainer
            .fiche-inner{"ng-repeat"=>"booking in bookings | filter: ??? "}
```

*note : this excerpt is in HAML but it doesn't matters since I use a precompalitor to get the .html*

Comment: Unrelated note: If you're using Angular, there's no reason to use server-side templating. Simple .html files should do, as your server should only be processing data via an API for efficiency's sake. Food for thought.

Comment: Okay, actual comment: What have you tried?  `booking in bookings | filter: month` didn't work?

Comment: thx blesh, i use a precompilator to render the .html, I prefere to use HAML rather than HTMLto edit my template :)

Comment: But if you want templating, that is one of the main features of AngularJS. Using both HAML _and_ AngularJS is a bit of a performance waste with little actual profit.

Comment: I use HAML only on my local workspace, files are precompilated with Codekit who keeps the Angular templating. It's just my prefered way to output .html

Comment: @KevinGranger ah, well that's a great choice if your team prefers it. I was just trying to be helpful with my suggestion.  Could we possibly see a plunker or a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is very clever :)

```
booking in bookings | filter: month
```